# Where are local APIC addresses in QEMU?

Tags: linux, qemu, x86

According to Intel's document, `FEE0 0000H` to `FEE0 03F0H` is the range of local APIC. However, examining it from QEMU console, I can only find the value 0 there:

```
(qemu) x/128b 0xfee00000
fee00000: 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
fee00008: 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
fee00010: 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
fee00018: 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
fee00020: 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
fee00028: 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
fee00030: 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
fee00038: 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
fee00040: 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
fee00048: 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
fee00050: 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
fee00058: 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
fee00060: 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
fee00068: 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
fee00070: 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
fee00078: 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
```

I checked 128 bytes to see if anything different than 0. At least, `FEE0 0030H` should contain a different value since it is where APIC version is in.

Paging is disabled, so there's no virtual memory; just physical:

```
(qemu) info mem
PG disabled
```

But, `info lapic` command reports actual initial values:

```
(qemu) info lapic 
dumping local APIC state for CPU 0 

LVT0     0x00008700 active-hi level                             ExtINT (vec 0)
LVT1     0x00008400 active-hi level                             NMI   
LVTPC    0x00010000 active-hi edge  masked                      Fixed  (vec 0)
LVTERR   0x00010000 active-hi edge  masked                      Fixed  (vec 0)
LVTTHMR  0x00010000 active-hi edge  masked                      Fixed  (vec 0)
LVTT     0x00030010 active-hi edge  masked         periodic     Fixed  (vec 16)
Timer    DCR=0x2 (divide by 8) initial_count = 4096
SPIV     0x000001ff APIC enabled, focus=off, spurious vec 255
ICR  0x000c4610 physical edge assert all
ICR2     0x00000000
ESR  0x00000000
ISR  (none)
IRR  (none)
```

So, where are these values?